# M2: Product ID error after update to 2.2.2

Tags: magento2.2.2

After updating to Magento 2.2.2 I'm receiving this error in admin while trying to edit bundle products:

> Item (Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Stock\Status) with the same ID
>   "XXXX" already exists.

Bundle products are not listed in frontend either.

Comment: This issue because `row_id` and `entity_id` column not similar ;(

Comment: This issue because `row_id` and `entity_id` column not similar ;(

Answer (score 0):

i had that on 2.1.9, too.
I found out that some attribute values were duplicated in the database.
in my case it was a brand attribute which was added twice. the secind time, i ran into that problem, i had categories with keys duplicated. maybe you check your attributes and categories, reset the index and reindex.